# Slicing list of lists to get rid of the first item

Tags: python, list, slice

How do I slice to get rid of "Hello", "World" and "Monty" in a list of lists? I have:

```
lst1 = [["Hello",1,2,3],["World",4,5,6],["Monty",7,8,9]]
```

I want:

```
lst2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: you need to be clearer, are you trying to exclude strings from each sublist or the first element from each sublist or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a slice of a list `lst` starting with the second element using `lst[1:]`. To do it for each sublist you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst1 = [["Hello", 1, 2, 3], ["World", 4, 5, 6], ["Monty", 7, 8, 9]]
>>> lst2 = [lst[1:] for lst in lst1]
>>> lst2
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reach it with a list comprehension and get in each iteration the last elements beside the first of the nested list by using the [1:] selector.

```
lst1 = [["Hello", 1,2,3], ["World",4,5,6],["Monty",7,8,9]]

lst2 = [item[1:] for item in lst1]
print (lst2)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```